# Are most of the NoSQL databases key/value stores technically?

Tags: mongodb, table, nosql, cassandra, document-oriented

[This video](https://youtu.be/pHAItWE7QMU?t=3m18s) distinguishes between three (main) types of NoSQL databases:

1. Key/Value store
2. Tabular
3. Document oriented

Do these types differ in how they technically store their data or can they be considered all to be key/value stores since even the tabular ones (like Cassandra) may have variable column count and most likely serialize the column values to a string? And the documents (MongoDB) are also only strings in the end... I suppose all types generate an unique id for their "values/data". So are all the 3 types key/value on low level?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB is not a key-value store; its documents are *not* just strings in the end. MongoDB stores its data in a format called BSON (Binary JSON), which allows for complex structures including various data types, strings being just one of them. See the [BSON Spec](http://bsonspec.org/faq.html) for more details, for example:

> Examples
> The following are some example documents (in JavaScript / Python style syntax) and their corresponding BSON representations.
>
> Example 1:  `{"hello": "world"}`

```
\x16\x00\x00\x00                   // total document size  
\x02                               // 0x02 = type String  
hello\x00                          // field name  
\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00          // field value  
\x00                               // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')
```

> Example 1:  `{"BSON": ["awesome", 5.05, 1986]}`

```
\x31\x00\x00\x00
\x04BSON\x00
\x26\x00\x00\x00
\x02\x30\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00awesome\x00
\x01\x31\x00\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40
\x10\x32\x00\xc2\x07\x00\x00
\x00
\x00
```